# How can I declare a char variable with my name on it?

Tags: c#

I don't know if I can declare it with only one variable. I'm begginer btw.

```
char a = {'j', 'o', 'h', 'n'},
```

is it right ?

Comment: `string myName = "john"` ?

Comment: The `char` data type is for a *single character*. For a sequence of characters, use `string`. If that doesn't help, please provide more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: _is it right ?_ What did the compiler say?

Comment: thanks. I was wondering if I can but 'char is a data type for only a single character' so I got the answer. I wasn't coding, it was a provocative question in one of the exams which I'll undergo.

Answer (score 0):

The **string** declaration in C# is as below : 
using System;

```
namespace StringApplication {

   class Program {

      static void Main(string[] args) {
         //from string literal and string concatenation
         string fname, lname;
         fname = "Rowan";
         lname = "Atkinson";

         char []letters= { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l','o' };
         string [] sarray={ "Hello", "From", "Tutorials", "Point" };

         string fullname = fname + lname;
         Console.WriteLine("Full Name: {0}", fullname);

         //by using string constructor { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l','o' };
         string greetings = new string(letters);
         Console.WriteLine("Greetings: {0}", greetings);

         //methods returning string { "Hello", "From", "Tutorials", "Point" };
         string message = String.Join(" ", sarray);
         Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", message);

         //formatting method to convert a value
         DateTime waiting = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10, 17, 58, 1);
         string chat = String.Format("Message sent at {0:t} on {0:D}", waiting);
         Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", chat);
      }
   }
}
```

Output Produced by it

```
Full Name: RowanAtkinson
Greetings: Hello
Message: Hello From Tutorials Point
Message: Message sent at 5:58 PM on Wednesday, October 10, 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as the array of the character if you want name in char.

`char []a= { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l','o' };`

Comment: it is the array of the characters